# SQL/PHP sort fields from a form to make insert

Tags: php, sorting, foreach, insert

I've got a form which users can add new rows by clicking on a button and automatically, it adds +1 on the field's name.

So for example, I've got my `train_id_1`, `train_type_1` and my user wants to add a new one, so now I've got `train_id_2` and `train_type_2`.

In order to save this in my database, I would like to `sort` and `seperate train_type_1 / train_type_2...` to make a `foreach` and then to save in my `database`.

So, the `var_dump` of my `$_POST` looks like :

```
array (size=60)
  'train_id_1' => string ' 07:36' (length=6)
  'train_type_1' => string ' -Z' (length=3)
  'user_id_1' => string 'CPN' (length=3)
  'event_criter_1' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'test' (length=4)
      1 => string '234' (length=3)
      2 => string '532' (length=3)
  'train_id_2' => string ' 08:32' (length=6)
  'train_type_2' => string ' -X' (length=3)
  'user_id_2' => string 'CPN' (length=3)
  'event_criter_2' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'TESTG' (length=5)
      1 => string 'GGG' (length=3)
      2 => string 'AETG' (length=4)
  'train_id_3' => string ' 08:36' (length=6)
  'train_type_3' => string ' -Z' (length=3)
  'user_id_3' => string 'CPN' (length=3)
  'event_criter_3' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
  'train_id_4' => string ' 09:04' (length=6)
  'train_type_4' => string ' -X' (length=3)
  'user_id_4' => string 'CPN' (length=3)
  'event_criter_4' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
```

Do you know how I can make `abcd_1` separate from `abcd_2` to make my `foreach` (or another solution) ?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need them sorted

Comment: Not really to "sort" but to "organize" them, I don't have abcd_1, abcd_2... in my database but only abcd and I would like to make 2 insert queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through your array, matching `_1` and insert the posted elements as one row.  Then increment and match `_2` etc..

```
$postedElements = $_POST;
$elementsPerRow = 4;
$numRows = count($postedElements)/$elementsPerRow;
// loop through the number of 'rows' to insert
for($i=1;$i<=$numRows;$i++){
     // Build an array to store matched elements to insert 
     $elementsToInsert = array();
     //process the complete _POST array each time...
     foreach($postedElements as $name => $value){
        // ...get the 'row' (the bit after the underscore)...
        //list($value,$row) = explode('_',$name); // doesn't work for 2 underscores..
        $row = end(explode($name)); // This will
        if($row == $i){
              // ...and add elements that match to an insert array
              // $elementsToInsert[] = $name; 
              $elementsToInsert[$name] = $value;
        }
    }
    // insert $elementsToInsert into DB
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work...
I can't get the values of _1, _2 and do for example $elementsToInsert['abcd']['1'] :/

Comment: $elementsToInsert[$value][$row]

Comment: oooooh crap ! Notice: Undefined index: event. 
Event is an array in an array.   'event_criter_1' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'test' (length=4)
      1 => string '234' (length=3)
      2 => string '532' (length=3)

Comment: Arrrgh!  2 underscores! - I'll change the answer..  ..there ya go.

Comment: Yes I've seen that when I removed "event", I was getting " Notice: Undefined index: user in". I'm trying the new one.

Comment: Ok, now I've got this : Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference. Maybe should I use array_shift ?

Comment: array_shift returns the first value, and shortens the array.  `$row` needs to be the last value.  Use `array_pop()` instead, this also returns the last value of an array.

Comment: You are my hero! Here is what I added for this to work:   $nameExploded = explode('_',$name);
        $row = end($nameExploded); // This will
Thank you!

Comment: Cool.  Can you remember to mark the solution as accepted if it has solved your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think, at first You need to have a amount of records in `array` through `count($arr)`. Then use usual `for` loop:

```
//output of field names
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
    //Work with array
}
```

Make a new `array`.

Then add a data from loop into new `array`.

I think it could help You.

And by which reason You need to sort them?